# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (23,) and (1,)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to plot theta vs eta using a predefined eta array to calculate theta. I keep getting the error message: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (23,) and (1,). What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np

# Definition of the array of eta for plotting
eta = np.array([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.6, 3, 3.4, 3.8, 4.2, 4.6, 5.0, 5.6, 6.2, 7.0, 8.0])
 
# Function to generate theta
def func_theta(eta, Pr):
   fdoubleprime=np.array([0.33206, 0.33199, 0.33147, 0.33008, 0.32739, 0.32301, 0.31659, 0.30787, 0.29667, 0.28293, 0.26675, 0.24835, 0.20646, 0.16136, 0.11788, 0.08013, 0.05052, 0.02948, 0.01591, 0.00543, 0.00155, 0.00022, 0.00001])
   g=fdoubleprime**Pr
   num=0.0
   for i in range(len(eta)-1):
       num+=0.5*((eta[i+1]-eta[i]) * (g[i+1]+g[i]))
   den=0.0
   for j in range(22):
       den+=0.5*((eta[j+1]-eta[j]) * (g[j+1]+g[j]))
   theta= 1-num/den   
    
   return (theta)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(4,3))
plt.plot(eta, func_theta(eta, 0.5), color='black')

plt.xlabel('$\\eta$')
plt.ylabel('$\\theta$')

plt.text(2, 0.4, 'Pr=0.5')
plt.text(1.5, 0.3, '0.8')

plt.xlim(0, 4)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.grid()
```

Comment: your `num` and `den` are scalar values so theta is also a scalar value. Did you actually intend to sum all the `num` and `den` values?

Comment: What does `func_theta(eta, 0.5)` produce?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate `num` and `den` values at every `eta`, and then use `num` and `den` to create an array of `theta` values to plot against `eta`. `func_theta(eta, 0.5)` produces `theta` using the `eta` array and `Pr=0.5`.

Comment: Also the formulas for numerator and denominator are DITTO, all the theta values will be zero. Also, seeing the way you are calculating, you'll end up with 22 theta values and 23 eta values.